# can someone please explain the syntax of the conditional operator below and what exactly it's doing

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

below I provided two examples (i.e. a and b). Looking at the conditional operator in basic form (example b), I cannot wrap my head around how:

```
(root = document.documentElement) || (root = document.body.parentNode)
```

in example a

results in a boolean value that causes the operator to either use 'root' or 'document.body'.

a. conditional operator in the form I don't understand:

`(((root= document.documentElement) || (root= document.body.parentNode))
    && typeof root.scrollLeft == 'number' ? root : document.body).scrollLeft`

b. conditional operator in basic form:

```
(conditional test) ? if true do this : if false do this;
```

Can some please give me a breakdown of what exactly is happening in example a? Thanks.

The goal is to use this code to access the scroll amount done to the  viewport area in a browser window for scripts without access to the window.scrollX and window.scrollY properties.

Comment: `||` returns its _first operand_ (not a boolean) if it can be evaluated to truthy, otherwise it returns _the last operand_. The evaluation is said to be lazy, i.e. if the first operand is evaluated to truthy, the second operand is never evaluated.

Comment: Look at it like it returns one or the other, based on the condition, which contains `&` in the case you don't understand. So, `root` or `document.body` is returned to get `.scrollLeft` on.

Comment: ah! my minds interpretation of your comments: (between documentElement and document.body.parentNode, choose the root that evaluated to true). Then test typeof root.scrollLeft= 'number' against the root that evaluated to true. If the root's scrollLeft property value is a 'number' and passed the test return that root's scrollLeft property, otherwise if both roots weren't able to be evaluated to true or either didn't pass the typeof root.scrollLeft= 'number' test return document.body.scrollLeft. I understand better. Thanks.

Comment: like Teemu said, if the first operand(in this case, documentElement) is true, | | won't even bother evaluating document.body.parentNode. Meaning that only one of these roots will be used. This way we have a chance to check if either of these root elements exist within a browser's DOM so we can access .scrollLeft

Comment: On a final note, how does documentElement or document.body.parentNode evaluate to a true or false value? if when printed out to the console they're basically a copy of your <html> root element. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An expression with a logical operator is always evaluated in the "most lazy" way possible (from left to right). This means in case of the "or" operator `||`, that it is only evaluated until the first "truthy" value has been found. Evaluating the second term could not change the result anymore. Had it been the "and" operator `&&` the evaluation would stop after the first "falsy" value. In JavaScript the "real" value is returned though and not only a `true` or `false`. This makes the construction a powerful one.

Another point to note would be that "almost everything has a value" in JavaScript: even an assignment expression returns the value of the variable on the left side after the assignment.

**Edit:**

If you *wanted to*, you could even further slim down the above expression to:

```
(typeof (root = document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode)
 .scrollLeft == 'number' ? root : document.body).scrollLeft
```

leaving out the `&&` operator. But this is probably *not* an improvement in terms of "readability".

Comment: Just a small nitpick. [Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) is not a statement, it's an expression, though it behaves exactly as you've described. Statements are not evaluated to any specific value, only expressions are always evaluated.

Comment: @teemu-callmewhateveryouwant, thanks for the hint! I will edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This thing is called **Short Circuit Evaluation**. Basically JS logical operators are evaluated from ***left to right***. This feature comes handy when you want to assign some value to a variable based on the `OR or AND` logic. For examples

```
true || true;
// true
true || false;
// true
false || false;
// false
```

Here if the left statement is `true` then it will not check the right side condition & return that left side value this is called short circuit evaluation.

For more information read this https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-ff22b2f5608c

Answer (score 0):

In a simple and intuitive way, you can think about the two expressions as the functions below:

```
(root = document.documentElement) || (root = document.body.parentNode)
```

which means:

```
function test() {
  root = document.documentElement
  if (!root) {
    root = document.body.parentNode
  }
  return !!root
}
test()
```

```
(((root= document.documentElement) || (root= document.body.parentNode))
    && typeof root.scrollLeft == 'number' ? root : document.body).scrollLeft
```

basically means:

```
function test(){
  root = document.documentElement
  if (!root) {
    root = document.body.parentNode
  }
  if (root) {
    return typeof root.scrollLeft == 'number' ? root : document.body).scrollLeft
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
test()
```